# Detecting which radio button of many was checked using C# & XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, radio-button

In Android/Java there is a `RadioGroup` object which can contain many `RadioButtons`.  `RadioGroup` also has an `OnChanged` event which I can listen to and then ask it which `RadioButton` is now selected (and then get that selected radio buttons Id).

Is there a corresponding way to achieve the same thing in C#? It appears I need to respond to the `Checked` event for every `RadioButton` (although they could go to the same event handler), but then in the event handler I need to iterate through every `RadioButton` to see if it was checked?  This is a lot of code if I have many (e.g. 20) `RadioButton`.  Is there an easier way?

Comment: First, you mention `RadioGroup` and `RadioButton` but later you ask about `CheckBox`. Can you update your question to exactly state which control you're interested in please?

Comment: @LightBulb oopps yes, corrected. I mean RadioButton not checkbox

Comment: Basically, there's only 1 `RadioButton` in a group that can be checked (group is denoted either by `GroupName` property or by placing all `RadioButton`s in a container like `StackPanel`. Answer provided by @keyboardP is probably the simplest way to identify which one is checked and act accordingly. IMO, using the `Tag` property is simplest in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a property to identify the control such as the `Tag` property or the `Name` property. You then attempt to cast the `sender` in the event handler to a `CheckBox` type and retrieve the identifying property.

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;

    if(cb != null)
    {
        string cbName = cb.Name; 
    }
}
```

By using `as` instead of an explicit cast (`(CheckBox)sender`), you avoid throwing an exception should the cast not be valid. That is an unlikely scenario in this case if only CheckBoxes are assigned this event handler but it's good practice in other cases, unless you need to throw an exception for whatever reason.

Comment: Selected as answer for specifically mentioning use of the Tag/Name to identify which RadioButton is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Normally in windows event handlers there is a sender parameter which can be cast to the appropriate control type that raised the event ... eg.

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
}
```

Now you know explicitly which CheckBox was checked, at the time the checked event occured.

So in your case, you would hook the same event handler up to all the CheckBoxes, and then identify the newly checked CheckBox with the `chk` variable.